# Is it possible to index into two dimensions of a three-dimensional array using arrays of indices?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have read through the examples [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=doc_12b), but it does not seem to include the following case.

Let `A` be a three dimensional array with dimensions `128 x 128 x 3`.

I want to pick sets of 3 integers at random from this array, by picking random pairs for the first two dimensions. This is my current attempt:

```
rng(1);                                         
choicex = randi(128, 1, 16)                
choicey = randi(128, 1, 16)                 
random_values = A(choicex, choicey,:)
```

Unfortunately, this the matrix `random_values` is now `16 x 16 x 3`, when I want it to be `16 x 3`. 
Taking one slice of this does not work because then either all the first indices would be the same or all the second indices would be the same.
I do not require that `random_values` carries the original indices.

Is there any way to achieve this in matlab directly with index notation, without writing a for loop?

Per the given answer, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. [`randi(nmax, i, j)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) returns a size `(i,j)` matrix of random integers from `1..nmax`. In your case, `nmax` obviously has to be 128, not 256.
2. matlab has 1-based indexing, not 0-based, so do not subtract 1.

This works for me:

```
>> A = randn(128,128,3);
>> choicex = randi(128, 1, 16);
>> choicey = randi(128, 1, 16);
>> B = A(choicex, choicey,:);
>> size(B)

ans =

    16    16     3
```

But this will give all triples that are on all combinations of the given rows and columns, so 256 triples in total. What you really want can be achieved with [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), but it is not an easy expression:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), repmat(choicex,3,1), repmat(choicey,3,1), ...
    repmat([1;2;3],1,16)))
```

or with a few characters less:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), [1;1;1]*choicex, [1;1;1]*choicey, [1;2;3]*ones(1,16)))
```

Comment: +1, Your answer does solve the error, but I'm trying to get 16 sets of 3 values, not 256 sets of 3 values.

Comment: If I replaced `16` with `4` above, it would get me 16 values, but there would be shared indices among the points selected.